# extjs remove space in west region of panel-toolbar

Tags: extjs, padding

How do I remove this space shown in picture below?  I've tried changing padding and margins and nothing is working.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1c3f

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting `style` instead of `bodyStyle` in the toolbar config

```
{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'left',
    style: 'padding: 0; margin: 0;',
    items: [ ... ]
}
```